# Pass down a tree of unknown length to the end node?

Tags: angular

Having a go at Angular for the first time, and I'm struggling to work out how what I want is achievable.

I have made two simple interfaces, a Project type and a folder type.

A project can contain folders and files, a folder can contain folders and files, so the depth of folders within folders in theory knows no bounds.

The files at this point are irrelevant.

Something like:

```
interface Project {
    name: string;
    folders: Folder[];
    files: any[]
    openStatus: boolean;
}

interface Folder {
  name: string;
  folders: Folder[];  //Not sure if having 'Folder' within itself is going to cause me problems.  
  files: any[];
  openStatus: boolean;
}
```

In my head I picture the structure looking like the below, essentially as you would expect a file directory.

```
--Project
 --Folder
  --Folder
   --Folder
    --Folder
     ...
 --Folder
  --Folder
   --Folder
```

I want to create a nav bar which can essentially keep going deeper into the subsequent folders until it gets to the end of the tree.

So I have created this (probable monstrosity):

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let project of projects; index as i;" class="nav-list">
      <button class="nav-secondary-button" (click)="changeProjectVisibilityStatus(project)">{{ project.name }}</button>
      <div *ngIf="project.folders.length != 0" [hidden]="!project.openStatus">
         <li *ngFor="let folder of project.folders; index as i;">
            <button class="nav-secondary-button" (click)="changeFolderVisibilityStatus(folder)">{{ folder.name }}</button>
            <div *ngIf="folder.folders.length != 0" [hidden]="!folder.openStatus">
               <li *ngFor="let folder of folder.folders; index as i;">
               <button class="nav-secondary-button">{{ folder.name }}</button>
               </li>
            </div>
         </li>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works as I would like, but only to the depth I choose to write it out to, and so I would have to set a hard limit on the depth.

Is there a way of looping until I find the bottom? There isn't a type of ngWhile (is there?!) and I can't see how I can make NgFor do this.

Now I have written this out I'm thinking I might be able to do it with a folder component that displays a folder component within itself if it contains folders, but I feel like the references are going to be circular and cause issues. I will try this out tomorrow evening to see if I get anywhere.

Always appreciative of any insight!

Comment: Can you also look into angular material tree component. For what I see I think you could make use of it for nested item selection.  https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: Having property of same type  shouldn't be an issue it self. Since interfaces  just describe your data structure. Now if you purposely moved a "main" folder into one of the child folders somehow, then yes you will get a circular reference. That is not gonna break something right way, only if call a recursive method, like json serialization.

Comment: Kelum - Thanks for pointing out the tree component in angular material, I had not spotted it. I think that is going to be the easiest way to go looking at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: Tree component from angular material has worked perfectly, thank you for setting me on that path, Angular docs were very clear on usage which is great.